# How to extract accountId from oauth2 token in webfilter

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Im using webflux in my program and oauth2 security (`keycloack as UAA server`) I want to extract some information from oauth2 jwt and I do it well . but i need to get some information in filter .
when I use my old method it not work in filter (`WebFilter`) .
Is there any way to parse token and get information from it ?
Is my way correct or I should extract it using `springSecurityFilterChain` instead of WebFilter?
I want check accountId in token with accountId in url that client send using filter.

Hear is my code to extract accountId it not work in WebFilter but it work when i use it services or controller

```
  public class SecurityFilter implements WebFilter {
    
    
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
           ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication).map(Principal::getName).filter((accountId) -> accountId.equals(clientAccountId)

.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new SystemException("401 ERROR")));;
          return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    
    }
```

Hear is my second way to extract accountId :

```
public class SecurityFilter implements WebFilter {


    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
      serverWebExchange.getPrincipal().map(Principal::getName).filter((accountId) -> accountId.equals(clientAccountId). .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new SystemException("401 ERROR")));;
      return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);

}
```

and my security config is :

```
 @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
              //  .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new HttpStatusServerAccessDeniedHandler(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor());
        return http.build();
    }
```

I think i should have another `SecurityWebFilterChain` method that do this for me ??

Comment: What is your problem here ? Is your problem that your filter never returns 401?

Comment: one is that i can not get pathVariable in  filter and last on is that my filter does not return 401

Comment: I am not sure but i think you also need to have defaultIfEmpty after exchange.getPrincipal() so just test it when you dont pass token what happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for smth like this

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    var clientAccountId = "clientId";
    return exchange.getPrincipal()
            .map(Principal::getName)
            .flatMap((accountId) -> {
                if (accountId.equals(clientAccountId) && exchange.getRequest().getPath().value().equals("/my/api")) {
                    return Mono.just(accountId);
                }
                return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("401 ERROR"));
            })
            .flatMap(tokenJwt -> chain.filter(exchange))
            .onErrorResume(r -> {
                exchange.getResponse().setRawStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
            });
}
```

Note: that when you are using reactive then until you or spring subscribe to it it wont be executed.